# Not able to Parse this JSON Array . with sub arrays and objects

Tags: android, json, api, networking

JSON that I want to parse.
Both JSON data that I want to parse. And my mainActivty code is provided please have a look.
I have accessed the JSON array and looped over it get Object of 1st element and try to get details from first element, Unfortunately i am not able to get them. I tried to Log my arrayListed returned from postExecute. it still shows size =0..

```
[
 {
"score": 24.910917,
"show": {
  "id": 13,
  "url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/13/the-flash",
  "name": "The Flash",
  "type": "Scripted",
  "language": "English",
  "genres": [
    "Drama",
    "Action",
    "Science-Fiction"
  ],
  "status": "Running",
  "runtime": 60,
  "premiered": "2014-10-07",
  "officialSite": "http://www.cwtv.com/shows/the-flash/",
  "schedule": {
    "time": "20:00",
    "days": [
      "Tuesday"
    ]
  },
  "rating": {
    "average": 8.1
  },
  "weight": 99,
  "network": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "The CW",
    "country": {
      "name": "United States",
      "code": "US",
      "timezone": "America/New_York"
    }
  },
  "webChannel": null,
  "externals": {
    "tvrage": 36939,
    "thetvdb": 279121,
    "imdb": "tt3107288"
  },
  "image": {
    "medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/129/323466.jpg",
    "original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/129/323466.jpg"
  },
  "summary": "<p>After a particle accelerator causes a freak storm, CSI Investigator Barry Allen is struck by lightning and falls into a coma. Months later he awakens with the power of super speed, granting him the ability to move through Central City like an unseen guardian angel. Though initially excited by his newfound powers, Barry is shocked to discover he is not the only \"meta-human\" who was created in the wake of the accelerator explosion -- and not everyone is using their new powers for good. Barry partners with S.T.A.R. Labs and dedicates his life to protect the innocent. For now, only a few close friends and associates know that Barry is literally the fastest man alive, but it won't be long before the world learns what Barry Allen has become...The Flash!</p>",
  "updated": 1532242720,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/13"
    },
    "previousepisode": {
      "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/1426878"
    },
    "nextepisode": {
      "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/1473791"
    }
  }
}
},
{
"score": 22.392826,
"show": {
  "id": 528,
  "url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/528/the-flash",
  "name": "The Flash",
  "type": "Scripted",
  "language": "English",
  "genres": [
    "Action",
    "Adventure",
    "Science-Fiction"
  ],
  "status": "Ended",
  "runtime": 60,
  "premiered": "1990-09-20",
  "officialSite": null,
  "schedule": {
    "time": "20:30",
    "days": [

    ]
  },
  "rating": {
    "average": 8.6
  },
  "weight": 71,
  "network": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "CBS",
    "country": {
      "name": "United States",
      "code": "US",
      "timezone": "America/New_York"
    }
  },
  "webChannel": null,
  "externals": {
    "tvrage": 5781,
    "thetvdb": 78650,
    "imdb": "tt0098798"
  },
  "image": {
    "medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/4/11360.jpg",
    "original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/4/11360.jpg"
  },
  "summary": "<p>The Flash is Barry Allen, a police scientist, who was working one night during a terrible thunder storm when a bolt of lightning crashes through the lab window, electrocuting him. Barry survives and soon learns that he is now able to move at almost incomprehensible speed.</p>",
  "updated": 1509496066,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/528"
    },
    "previousepisode": {
      "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/47947"
    }
  }
}
},
```

## MainActivity

```
 package com.vineet.moviesapp;

 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "LOG MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnGet = findViewById(R.id.btnGet);

    btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            updateTextView();
        }
    });
}



public void updateTextView(){
    NetworkTask networkTask = new NetworkTask();
    networkTask.execute("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=flash");
}

class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String stringUrl = strings[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
            if (scanner.hasNext()){
                String s = scanner.next();
                return s;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList = parseJson(s);
        Log.d(TAG,"onPostExec"+ movieArrayList.size());
    }
}

ArrayList<Movie> parseJson(String s){
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        JSONArray root = new JSONArray(s);

        for(int i=0; i<root.length(); i++){

            JSONObject object = root.getJSONObject(i);

            Integer score = object.getInt("score");
            String name = object.getJSONObject("show").getString("name");
            String language = object.getJSONObject("show").getString("language");
            String image = object.getJSONObject("show").getJSONObject("image").getString("medium");
            Double rating = object.getJSONObject("show").getDouble("average");

            Movie movie = new Movie(score,name,language,image,rating);
            movies.add(movie);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return movies;
}
}
```

I have tried parsing the data my way. But was not able to parse it. please help me and let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: The json you posted is missing a trailing `]` instead of the comma. Is this true in your application as well?

Comment: No. i have just posted few objects from api that why you are not able to see ]

Answer (score 0):

at first look it may be this

```
    Integer score = object.getInt("score");
```

since in your json score is "score": 24.910917 . which is a double.
also in this line

```
    Double rating = object.getJSONObject("show").getDouble("average");
```

the json is

```
"rating": {
    "average": 8.1
  },
```

so it should be

```
 Double rating = object.getJSONObject("show").getJSONObject("rating").getDouble("average");
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this its working now But I want to ask one more I have JSON data of 10 objects but after parsing I am only getting data for 4 objects/?

Comment: most likely the parsing is failing and getting caught in the try catch. please post the  stack trace of the parsing. you can test by putting a break point on         e.printStackTrace(); and see if it gets hit

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to distract from Tomer Shemesh's answer, but if you do not have control over the API you are accessing then I would suggest that you use the `opt` methods to access the values in the JSON string. The `opt` methods provide the ability to add an optional value if the key is not available for some reason. For example you could try this:

```
JSONArray root = new JSONArray(s);
for(int i=0; i<root.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = root.getJSONObject(i);

    Double score = object.optDouble("score", -1);

    JSONObject showObject = object.getJSONObject("show");
    String name = showObject.optString("name", "Name NA");
    String language = showObject.optString("language", "Language NA");

    JSONObject imageObject = showObject.getJSONObject("image");
    String image = imageObject.optString("medium", "Image Medium NA");

    JSONObject ratingObject = showObject.getJSONObject("rating");
    Double rating = ratingObject.optDouble("average", -1);

    Movie movie = new Movie(score,name,language,image,rating);
    movies.add(movie);
}
```

Notice for example that `showObject.optString("name", "Name NA");` gives you an optional value if the key "name"  is not available--if it does not exist you get the string "Name NA" instead of causing an error. Likewise, `ratingObject.optDouble("average", -1);` will return "-1" if the key "average" is not available.

Example: if you just use `getString("name");'  and the "name" key is not present in the JSON string, then you will get an error and the loop will stop. If however, you have`optString("name", "NA");' and the "name" key is not present in the JSON string you will get "NA" and the loop will continue.